# TemplateNotFound error Flask using render_template on Pythonanywhere

Tags: python, flask, pythonanywhere

I have been searching for a solution to this problem since the past two hours and have seen similar questions here but the solutions don't seem to be working. I am a beginner in Flask and Pythonanywhere so I feel the solution could be something really silly that I might be missing.

The template is called givp.html and everything is organized this way:
home > user > mysite > templates >givp.html
and 
home>user>mysite>apllic.py

The code I've been using is:

```
app=Flask(__name__,template_folder='/home/user/mysite/templates')

 return render_template('/home/user/mysite/templates/givp.html',lst=d)
```

Things are working fine on my local system but here I've been getting error messages. The last line of the error logs is:

> File
>   "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py",
>   line 64, in get_source
>       raise TemplateNotFound(template) TemplateNotFound: /home/user/mysite/templates/givp.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have already defined your `template_folder` while creating app instance in

```
app=Flask(__name__,template_folder='/home/user/mysite/templates')
```

so you have to provide just a template name (not a full path) while calling `render_template`.

Your code fixed:

```
app=Flask(__name__,template_folder='/home/user/mysite/templates')

return render_template('givp.html',lst=d)
```